# dc.js add multiple filters at once

Tags: dc.js

Is it possible to add a set of filters at once on a dc chart? For instance, say I have a pieChart, and an array of filter values to apply.

```
var osChart = dc.pieChart('#oschart');
```

And an input set of filters, say

```
var filters = ["linux", "mac osx", "windows", "solaris"]
```

How can I apply filters so that only one "filtered" event is generated?
I can do something like

```
for (var i=0; i < filters.length; i++) {
  osChart.filter(filters[i]);
}
```

However that would generate 4 `filtered` event.
I am applying filters based on what a user typed on a text box. When a filter is applied, I am making some ajax calls, and this tends to slow down if I apply filters one by one. I can avoid extra ajax calls if the filters can be set at once.

crossfilter has a function `filterFunction` which can get this task done, but I am not sure how I can apply that on a dc chart. Apply `filterFunction` on `osChart.dimension()` did not work. With the latest dc release, I saw some functions like `addFilterHandler` and `removeFilterHandler` however I cannot test and deploy that version right now.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code, which is somewhat convoluted, you can pass the array *inside another array* to `.filter()` (or the undocumented but unmagical [`.replaceFilter()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/base-mixin.js#L707)) without a performance penalty, because it will apply all of the filters before invoking the `filtered` event.

From the latest `.filter()` source, which uses handlers but has the same behavior:

```
    if (_ instanceof Array && _[0] instanceof Array && !_.isFiltered) {
        _[0].forEach(function (d) {
            if (_chart.hasFilter(d)) {
                _removeFilterHandler(_filters, d);
            } else {
                _addFilterHandler(_filters, d);
            }
        });
    } else if (_ === null) {
        _filters = _resetFilterHandler(_filters);
    } else {
        if (_chart.hasFilter(_)) {
            _removeFilterHandler(_filters, _);
        } else {
            _addFilterHandler(_filters, _);
        }
    }
    applyFilters();
    _chart._invokeFilteredListener(_);
```

So if it finds an array that does not have an `isFiltered` method, and that array's first element is also an array, it will iterate over the elements in the nested array.

For example, pass `[["linux", "mac osx", "windows", "solaris"]]` to filter on those four values. (Thanks @marcin for clarifying!)

Comment: ah, so it needs to be array in array, e.g. .replaceFilter([["linux", "mac osx", "windows", "solaris"]])

Comment: Really @marcin? That's surprising. Which chart are you working with?

Comment: pieChart. The first line of code in this answer (`if (_ instanceof Array && _[0] instanceof Array &&`) checks if the first element of array is array.

Comment: OMG it is even more convoluted than I thought. Thanks @marcin, I have edited my answer.