# Dc.js bar chart range extent not reflecting dimension data

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, dc.js

I have been using `chart.filter([new Date x, new Date x])` to set the range of the chart brush for a play function I am writing. It looks fine on the bar chart as the selection moves properly but unfortunately the selection is not visualized in my graphic properly. I use `dimension.top(Infinity)` on filtered to send the data to the visualization function but instead of reflecting the set filter range it is aggregating each time it is changed.

For example filtering year a to year b will visualize 3 points. When chart is filtered to second set of years: year b to year c (3 points), it visualizes the new points between those two years but also includes those from year a to b (6 points, I want to show just those 3).

I am wondering if anyone can help with this issue?

Or maybe I am overlooking a dc function and implementing the filter wrong?

Comment: Please share a fiddle. That will help troubleshoot quickly

Comment: Is it that you need the range filter? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29041518/676195

Comment: Yes! that fixed the issue with it messing the filter ! Thank You